# Pipo M8 pro launchers

Tags: updates

I have a new Pipo M8 pro max tablet. I accidentally deleted the launchers when I tried to get rid of a few apps. I now realise that launchers are a necessary part of the android o/s. I have tried the Pipo website but it will not load. I know very little about adding upgrades and firmware but I might need to go down that road. Could anyone offer me any help or advice so that I can use my excellent tablet to its full potential?

Comment: Use any third party launcher like apex, Go launcher, Adw, Holo, Nova, KK launcher

Comment: Hi avirk thank you for the info. Is it a matter of simply downloading and installing or is there a process involved. I don't want to ruin anything

Comment: Its just matter to download and install, no root require nothing would be brick.

Comment: Any preferences on the launcher or are they all pretty much the same. I am an Android newbie so much research required; bricks, roots, flashed....all in good time, til then i ask and appreciate any responses

Comment: If you are on Ics, or JB apex,  nova,  and Kk launcher is good for me.  Apex is highly recommended due to easy interface. Just download free version from play store.